# How to prove the general formula for variance of binomial distribution

Tags: binomial-distribution

In the video from [Khan academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-statistics/random-variables-ap/binomial-mean-standard-deviation/v/variance-of-binomial-variable)m Khan tried to prove that the variance of the binormial distirbution follow the formula

$$ D(x)=np(1-p)$$

However, I am a bit confused about what he said in the video. He proved it by showing: $D(nX)=nD(x)=np(1-p)$

But I am not sure about the first equation sign. If I am not mistaken, shouldn't

$$D(nx)=n^2 D(x)$$

My question is shouldn't $D(nx)=n^2 D(x)$

Edit: I have edited it to use proper mathjax notation, or as far as I understand it, to hopefully make the viewing experience more pleasant. Also you don't need to watch the Khan Academy video, basially all he said was $D(nx)=nD(x)$

Comment: Please share all the relevant information in your post. It's not realistic to expect others to watch the video. Mathjax formatting of the equations also helps.

Comment: For use of Mathjax see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/instructions-on-how-to-use-latex-on-crossvalidated/1605#1605

Comment: The notation does not reflect the context.  Evidently you are asking about the variance of the sum of $n$ *iid* Bernoulli variables $X_i$ and *not* about $n$ times a single variable $X,$ which is what you take "$nX$" to mean.

Comment: I tried to fix your math markup. The complete formula have to be between dollar signs, not only a part!